# Ajax readyState returning always 0

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got a problem with this Ajax code, is returning 0 everytime I access 'readyState'. Don't know what the source of the problem is yet, any help would be appreciated:

```
var xhr = null;
function performAjax(inputUrl){

    // instantiate XMLHttpRequest object
    try{
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        alert("XMLHttpRequest");
    }
    catch(e){
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    // handle old browsers
    if( xhr == null ) {
        alert("Ajax not supported by your browser");
        return;
    }

    // get the URL
    var url = inputUrl;
    alert(inputUrl);
    // get Ajax answer
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handler();
    //alert(xhr.readyState);
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.send(null);
}

function handler() {

    alert("Handler: " + xhr.readyState + " Status: " + xhr.status);
    // handle only loaded requests
    if(xhr.readyState == 4) {   // state 4: that data has been received
        alert("here");
        if(xhr.status == 200) { 
            alert(xhr.reponseText);
        }
        else alert("Error with Ajax");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're assigning the handler function incorrectly:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = handler; // <--- THERE SHOULD BE NO PARENTHESES
```

When you *include* the parentheses, you're asking that the function be *called*. Without them, you're merely referring to the function, which is what you want.

Comment: @Sebastian no no -- it should **not** have parentheses; **the parentheses are the problem.**